# can't set correct content-Type in Ext.Ajax.request

Tags: extjs

Code is as below:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
url: url,
method: 'POST',
headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
jsonData: {
        textMatchStyle:"substring",
        fields: ["packageName","name","tableName"], 
        data: {_domain:null,_domainContext:{},operator:"and",criteria:[]},
        limit: 40,
        offset: 0
        }, 
success: function(response) {
    console.log('Success');     
},// function called on success
failure: function(result) {Ext.MessageBox.alert('Error', 'Some problem occurred');},
});
```

This should work according to Extjs documentation, but in request-header

```
Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded,text/javascript; charset=UTF-8
```

Which causes problem as my server requires post data in `application/json` format and not in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

I have searched this on ext-forums too but could not get it worked.

Is there Problem in my code or its bug in extjs?

Please help.

Comment: What version of ExtJS are you using? 4.1.1 seems fine.

Answer (score 3):

Everything is ok with your code because it works ok. I tested it in both IE9 and Chrome and as  you can see in the image:

[image]

You can see this working here: http://tinyurl.com/afeluoy

I can´t imagine a reason why your header is not setted okay but play with the it in jsfiddle to confirm it works properly.

Comment: thanks. Yes, I tested it on the link u provided, but my ext version is 2.0.2, as this(extjs) is part of another project signavio BPMN2.0, so can't upgrade my ext version :(, what to do?